# Is there an official Windows XP registry reference?

Tags: windows-xp, reference, registry

Is there an official Windows XP registry reference online somewehere? I see there's a reference for [Win 2000](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974061.aspx) and [Win 2003](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778196(v=ws.10).aspx) servers on MS technet, but I can't seem to find one for XP. Yes, I know that Win 2000 reference would be good enough (most things will be the same in XP anyway), but if there's an explicit reference for XP, I'd like to take a look at it.

EDIT: I didn't mean API reference. I'm looking for a reference with descriptions of registry keys, possible values, etc.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724880(VS.85).aspx

Comment: That link points to the Registry API reference, not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows 2000 Resource Kit comes with a help file called "Registry Reference" (regentry.chm).  If you have access to this older Resource Kit, this file is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Windows Internals, 4th ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619174), Chapter 4, Part 1: The Registry is *exactly* what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The registry is just a means of storing data. Large portions of it are inherently undocumented and subject to change. The registry was not designed to be closely defined, so there cannot be closely defined or complete documentation for it.

For specific situations (like "what values are allowed in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W32Time\Config\UpdateInterval`") you may find vendor documentation (in the MSDN in this case).

Comment: The question is about the documented, OS-specific parts of it. Undocumented or application-specific parts are not mentioned. So where on MSDN are the documented XP keys?

Comment: Erm... There is no difference between "application specific" and "OS specific". It's all "application specific", and part of it happens to come from Microsoft, and again part of *that* is documented on the MSDN. As to *where* - that's what search engines are for. I don't think there is a compendium.

Comment: Well, if i was able to find such a reference using a search engine, I wouldn't have asked the question...

Comment: If you are unable to find documentation, then chances are that there is no documentation. That's what I'm saying all the time. There is no compendium. Parts of the registry are documented and others are not, period.